# How to add developed Facebook application in a Company profile page?

Tags: facebook

i have two facebook accounts, one is for my personal, and other one is company profile.

i just developed facebook application (using personal account), but how can i add it into company profile account, to be accessible using left menu on FB page?

tnx in adv!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to go to the application profile page :

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=YOUR_APPLICATION_ID

You can also get there by going to facebook.com/developers then click on your application the right, then on the next page click "application profile page".

So when your on the "application profile page", on the lower left side there is "Add to my Page". Then you have a popup, you choose your page and "add to page" and voilà :)

Comment: adding, he needs to do this from a Facebook account that is admin on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook as changed the way we now do this.

You can check the announcement here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/

They've deprecated the Application profile page.

Bottom point, you now have to go to this address:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&redirect_uri={YOUR_URL}

where:

{YOUR_APP_ID} -> should be replaced with the APP ID generated by Facebook

{YOUR_URL} -> should be replaced with the address where your tab is hosted